# Find the speed of rotation of the disc

Tags: logical-deduction

This problem is an extension to the puzzle:
[Find the direction of the disc](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24058/find-the-direction-of-the-disc?newreg=4c3e84f5bc954b179118656fd1e658a7)

Using the answer provided there, I can find the direction of rotation of the disc. Now, how can I find the speed of rotation of the disc? And will I need any extra circuitry to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems trivial:

> Time for how long does a sensor give the same output, multiply it by 2 and you will get the time needed for one full revolution of a disc.